# loadkeys not working

Tags: keyboard, 15.10, dvorak

I want to learn how to switch the keyboard in a terminal to [BÉPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%89PO) (without being root), so I used the command `loadkeys fr-bepo`, but I am getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/ckbcomp: Can not find file "symbols/fr-bepo" in any known directory
```

I looked over the web for an hour, and they all said that the right command is `loadkeys fr-bepo`.

PS: I know that `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` allows to switch keyboard, but it demands root privileges, that's why I want to use `loadkeys`.

Comment: I use loadkeys in text mode. I have not tried that particular key configuration, but I often use the command line `sudo loadkeys se`. I think `loadkeys` wants elevated permissions (sudo) to work, at least for me. I often do it when I test iso files of Lubuntu and other Ubuntu flavours . (In a terminal window I use `setxkbmap se` without elevated persmissions. It is not quite clear if you want to do this in text mode or graphics mode.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer just after setting up the bounty lol.

In `Debian` derivatives (like `Ubuntu`), you have to install the package `console-data` with the command `sudo apt-get install console-data`

Then you can switch to bepo using this : `loadkeys dvorak-fr-bepo`.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, and thanks for sharing it :-)